# how to keep Electron window from being minimized

Tags: windows, electron

as the title says, i need to keep a window showing on the desktop but not on the top level, it's transparent and full-screen (*taskbar excluded, just the wallpaper area*), i put some widgets on the transparent window to make it look like it's on the desktop.

so, here the problem comes, how to keep it always on the desktop, not minimized by some global shortcuts like `win+D` or any other situations.

and considering user experience issues, we also cannot try to unregister/disable those shortcuts, or try to restore window after minimization (*avoid window flashing*).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`electron-disable-minimize` does work for electron@25.6.0

Comment: but something goes strange due to this function, the transparent window could be focused while the transparent part is clicked. after clicking the part which is supposed to be click-through, the window comes to the top level among other windows like it's focused